# Include variables into a playbook from an in-place rendered jinja2 template without intermediate file

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I need to create some variables, lists, etc that are dynamically generated from other variables -- think of a list of nodes for kubernetes built with for loop.

This can be done inside Ansible with the `set_fact` and looping through incrementally with a `default()`, adding each list item each loop, but I don't want to build up all these vars with tasks.

I want to use a template to build the list and then use the result as variables. This works fine if I render the template to a file, and then load it into the playbook with `vars_files` or `include_vars`, but I wonder if it is possible to skip the intermediate file and do an in-place render-template realize-variables?

`rendered_template.j2`

```
nodes:
{% for item in nodes_struct %}
  - name: "{{ item.name }}"
    ipaddress: "{{ item.ipaddress }}"
    networkifacename1: "enp1s0"
    networkifacename2: "enp2s0"
{% endfor %}
```

`playbook.yaml`

```
- hosts: all
  vars_files:
    - ../vars/rendered_template.yaml
```

or

```
- name: Render global variables
  include_vars: "../vars/rendered_template.yaml"
```

The above is just a very simple example from a snippet inside the template. Most of the solutions suggest building up the vars instead with playbook tasks using the `map` function or `nodes: |` construct. I was trying to avoid doing ~60 playbook tasks instead of 60 vars rendered from the template in-place, but maybe that's the only way.

Would have been nice if I could use something like

```
- name: show templating results
  set_fact:
    template_var: "{{ lookup('template', '../vars/rendered_template.j2') }}"
```

And then somehow flatten it into var space from the root of that rendered template var instead of getting to it like. code below does not work)

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ template_var.nodes }}"
```

Comment: What isn't working as expected when using `vars_files` or `include_vars`? Because your self answer looks like you're doing the exact equivalent, only with a superior level of complexity and verbosity (not talking about performance...)

Comment: I don't want to use an external intermediate file in this case. It would have no permanence, so I wanted to see if I could do all this processing in-band inside Ansible itself.

Comment: You don't need to use an intermediate file. A var file is basically a template, as far as your above examples are concerned. You just have to load that original file.

Comment: Yes, but in my case, the template has `for` loops, which you cannot just simply `include_vars`. You can do that for structures like `"varname: {% if my_group_var %}value{% else %}other_value{% endif %}"` in an include_vars file, but not all the other jinjia2 style free-form loops and such, like my example Q here.

Comment: The solutions below have for loops so I'm afraid I don't really get what is the problem. If you template just to get a yaml result you can include the template file directly (maybe with very minor fixes to do so).

Comment: And just to wipe a possible misunderstanding: a templated var content is interpreted when you use it (and each time you do so), not when you declare it. So you can perfectly include Vars based on registers which are not yet defined/populated. This will work as long as you don't use those variables before running the registering task (and you can always use the `default` filter to secure your playbook if needed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I went elsewhere and coaxed the answer to my Q. This code works for my purpose and is concise.

```
- set_fact:
    template_var: "{{ lookup('template', '../vars/rendered_template.j2') }}"

- set_fact:
    template_var_yaml: "{{ template_var | from_yaml }}"

- name: Convert to top-level
  set_fact:
    "{{ item.key }}": "{{ item.value }}"
  loop: "{{ template_var_yaml|dict2items }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.key }}"

- debug:
    var: nodes
```

Of course, it can be reduced down to

```
- name: Convert to top-level
  set_fact:
    "{{ item.key }}": "{{ item.value }}"
  loop: "{{ lookup('template', '../vars/rendered_template.j2')|from_yaml|dict2items }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.key }}"

- debug:
    var: nodes
```

Leaving the vars "namespaced" from inside `template_var.nodes` would also be useful so as not to pollute the top-level var space, but in my case, the source template variables were used extensively later by a bunch of roles I'm using that someone else made, so I need to keep them top-level.

Answer (score 2):

You're already most of the way there. You can do this:

```
nodes: |
  {% filter from_yaml %}
  {% for item in nodes_struct %}
  - name: "{{ item.name }}"
    ipaddress: "{{ item.ipaddress }}"
    networkifacename1: "enp1s0"
    networkifacename2: "enp2s0"
  {% endfor %}
  {% endfilter %}
```

Here's a runnable example:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    nodes_struct:
      - name: foo
        ipaddress: 1.1.1.1
      - name: bar
        ipaddress: 2.2.2.2

    nodes: |
      {% filter from_yaml %}
      {% for item in nodes_struct %}
      - name: "{{ item.name }}"
        ipaddress: "{{ item.ipaddress }}"
        networkifacename1: "enp1s0"
        networkifacename2: "enp2s0"
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfilter %}
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ nodes }}"
```

Running that playbook produces:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "ipaddress": "1.1.1.1",
            "name": "foo",
            "networkifacename1": "enp1s0",
            "networkifacename2": "enp2s0"
        },
        {
            "ipaddress": "2.2.2.2",
            "name": "bar",
            "networkifacename1": "enp1s0",
            "networkifacename2": "enp2s0"
        }
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: I like the `nodes: |` construct, which Vladimir also suggested.

Answer (score 1):

The iteration in *set_fact* or in a template can always be used when there are no filters or functions to create the structure in a pipe. But in your case, the template is overkill. Instead, you can put the common attributes into a dictionary

```yaml
  node_default:
    networkifacename1: enp1s0
    networkifacename2: enp2s0
```

and declare the list in the pipe

```yaml
  nodes: "{{ nodes_struct|product([node_default])|map('combine') }}"
```

gives what you want

```yaml
  nodes:
  - ipaddress: 1.1.1.1
    name: foo
    networkifacename1: enp1s0
    networkifacename2: enp2s0
  - ipaddress: 2.2.2.2
    name: bar
    networkifacename1: enp1s0
    networkifacename2: enp2s0
```

---

- Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    nodes_struct:
      - name: foo
        ipaddress: 1.1.1.1
      - name: bar
        ipaddress: 2.2.2.2

    node_default:
      networkifacename1: enp1s0
      networkifacename2: enp2s0

    nodes: "{{ nodes_struct|product([node_default])|map('combine') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: nodes|to_nice_json
```

gives the same in JSON

```yaml
  nodes:
    [
        {
            "ipaddress": "1.1.1.1",
            "name": "foo",
            "networkifacename1": "enp1s0",
            "networkifacename2": "enp2s0"
        },
        {
            "ipaddress": "2.2.2.2",
            "name": "bar",
            "networkifacename1": "enp1s0",
            "networkifacename2": "enp2s0"
        }
    ]
```

---

- You can put the declarations into your current vars files

```yaml
shell> cat vars/rendered_template.yaml 
node_default:
  networkifacename1: enp1s0
  networkifacename2: enp2s0
nodes: "{{ nodes_struct|product([node_default])|map('combine') }}"
```

The play below gives the same result

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    nodes_struct:
      - name: foo
        ipaddress: 1.1.1.1
      - name: bar
        ipaddress: 2.2.2.2

  tasks:

    - include_vars: rendered_template.yaml
    - debug:
        var: nodes|to_nice_json
```

See: [Resolving local relative path](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbook_pathing.html#resolving-local-relative-paths) why you can omit *vars* from the path *vars/rendered_template.yaml*

---

- You can simplify it if you still want to use the template

```yaml
nodes: |
  {% filter from_yaml %}
  {% for item in nodes_struct %}
  - {{ item|combine(node_default) }}
  {% endfor %}
  {% endfilter %}
```

Comment: This helps, and I really do need to learn the `map` filter better. But my template is far more complicated than the example I presented here, which is just a small snippet to show the task. I cannot use a smaller static vars file and then dynamic it inside the playbook -- my dynamic vars are all crafted from external calls to API systems before getting to the template-vars. I could use your example #2 code, but then I would have to build up all my vars in separate tasks, and I was trying to avoid. Some of the vars are dict's, so map is helpful in lieu of looping